# Imprimir los registros resultados de consulta con LIKE. mysql+python3

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Hola agradecería si alguien me pudiera ayudar con este problema. Quiero imprimir cada uno de los resultados que me arrojaría esta consulta como cuando se ejecuta en MySQL. Lo que quiero es por ejemplo obtener todos los registros que contengan la palabra "fuente" en la columna "Producto", varios productos la poseen en la tabla y me gustaría imprimir todos los resultados.

```
import MySQLdb

def consultar(Producto):

    try:
        db     = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","1234","pcsolution")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql    = ("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Producto LIKE ='"+Producto+"';")
        cursor.execute(sql)
        for (Codigo,Producto,Unidades) in cursor:            
            return Producto,Marca,Unidades
            db.commit()
            db.close()
    except:
        return ("Problemas de conexión")

Producto,Marca,Unidades = consultar("fuente")
print (Producto)
print (Marca)
print (Unidades)
```

Comment: No estoy seguro si funciona, pero puedes usar `pandas`. Intenta crear un dataframe con todos los productos:
 `productos = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE Producto LIKE %fuente%'  `
y luego : 
 `productos = pd.read_sql(productos,db)`

Comment: La respuesta de Gin me parece correcta. Adicionalmente, aconsejo sanear el valor del parámetro Producto, para evitar inyección de código SQL. Me parece curioso el uso de for para leer el resultset, ya que regresa la primer tupla y se sale debido a Return. Tu comentas que hay varios registros en la tabla que cumplen la condición, y que quieres obtener todos; en este caso sólo vas a obtener la primera tupla.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo tanto de python, pero sí de Mysql. En la sección donde enuncias el query sólo te hace falta incluir wildcard (comodines). [Aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) puedes leer al respecto de eso.
TL;DR: Agrega caracteres ***%*** al inicio y al final del parametro de consulta.

```
... where campo LIKE '%mi_parametro%';
```

Donde el caracter ***%*** es un comodín que significa "cualquier caracter cero o más veces".

Un saludo.